# How do you put a wrapper on a git command ex. git clone

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, wrapper

I'm trying to put a wrapper on the git clone command. In other words when I type the command "git clone user@server:group/repo.git" the git clone command would trigger a script and inside the script it would...
 1. Clone the git repository
 2. run the command "git init" on the repository

The reason I want to do this is because I want the clone projectors set up a certain way automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias the desired command:

```
alias git='mygit'
```

create a script `mygit`:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "clone" ] ; then
  # do your stuff here
  echo special behavior of git clone
else
  command git "$@"
fi
```

Save it somewhere the PATH variable is set to, e. g. `/home/user/bin`. `chmod 0770` it to make it executable.

When you type `git clone` in the shell you will fire up your special stuff. If you type e. g. `git push` the script will call the original git program.

Comment: Instead of `which git`, use `command git` to bypass the alias. That's built in to the shell (at least sh and bash both, I am much less sure about dash, zsh, and other shells). Then, use `"$@"` to avoid altering any user-supplied quoting (using `$*` causes re-interpretation of white space as defined by `$IFS`).

Comment: @torek thank you for these hints.